# Problem converting epoch to datetime - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, ipython

I have a pandas data frame showing timestamp in epoch. I need to convert it to datetime format.
The code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import datetime
import time

data_all = pd.ExcelFile('testData_02.xls')
data = pd.read_excel(data_all, 'TestData') 

GPSTime = data.loc[:,'GpsUtcTime'].astype(int) # In epochs
#GPSTime = pd.to_numeric(GPSTime,errors='coerce')
print(type(GPSTime))

datetime_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(GPSTime).strftime('%c')
Time_str = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(GPSTime))
```

The data type comes out as pandas.core.series.Series. I've tried converting it to int using .astype(int) and pd.to_numeric, but neither seems to work. The code returns the following error:

```
In [8]: %run NKS_combmorc
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Documents\Data\NKS_combmorc\NKS_combmorc.py in <module>
     35 #datetime_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(GPSTime).strftime('%c')
     36 #datetime_time = dates.num2date(GPSTime, tz='UTC')
---> 37 Time_str = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(GPSTime))
     38
     39

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    139         if len(self) == 1:
    140             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 141         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    142
    143     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

[error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6DsF.png

I've been staring myself blind at this for hours. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Can anyone see what I´m doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: how do the elements of `GPSTime` look like? Is it in seconds since the epoch (Unix time)? In general, you would use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) in pandas, not native Python datetime methods.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the previous answer, I misread the question. The problem is that the GPSTime is a Panda series. A possible solution would be to use the builtin functions in the Panda library.

```
time_strs = pd.to_datetime(GPSTime, unit='s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Note that this would return a Panda series of the datetime objects represented as strings.

Comment: I comment one of those lines out when I run the code. They do the same thing. They both yield the same error.